# Is it possible to run container inside container in k8s 1.21

Tags: docker, kubernetes

As we all know newest versions of k8s coming with container-d run time , in previous versions I was able to run container inside container (pod) , by using docker in docker approach,
How can I achieve this functionality now.

Comment: Docker-in-docker still perfectly works on any version. I successfully run it with containerd on 1.20

Comment: The fundamentals of using the Kubernetes API to launch additional Deployments haven't changed, if that's what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker should works in Kubernetes v1.19 as usually (also Docker in Docker), because:

> Kubernetes is [deprecating Docker](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.20.md#deprecation) as a container runtime after v1.20.

and:

> Dockershim is being removed from Kubelet as early as v1.23 release,
> which removes support for Docker as a container runtime as a result.

In that case you need to change your container runtime from Docker to another supported container runtime.

> One thing to note: If you are relying on the underlying docker socket
> (`/var/run/docker.sock`) as part of a workflow within your cluster
> today, moving to a different runtime will break your ability to use
> it. This pattern is often called Docker in Docker. There are lots of
> options out there for this specific use case including things like
> [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko),
> [img](https://github.com/genuinetools/img), and
> [buildah](https://github.com/containers/buildah).

More information on the [official Kubernetes page](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/)

Comment: I have explored kaniko , it is to build and push image some container registry , but in my  case we are using  Azure devops pipeline with Agents(container images ), in these we have docker installed for  running  images . now we are unable to run images because of /var/run/docker.sock issue .if I use kaniko also coming to problem statement, build and push will be completed with kaniko , how can I run Images in side container

Comment: You have a related question to the original with new details. So, please create a new question to get relevant answer. You can link back to the original for reference.
p.s. You changed your question after the answer provided: k8s from 1.19 to 1.21 This is not a good practice, since it may invalidate the answers you received.